# Should I kill off one of the plants from a polyembryonic citrus seed to let the other grow?

Tags: indoors, seeds, seedlings, citrus

I am growing some indoor citrus trees from seeds and found the seeds to mostly all sprout two plants. They are all about 1.5 inches tall right now and for each pair of plants one is clearly larger and taller than the other. I am worried that having two growing so close to each other will end up hurting both.

[image]

I was thinking of just cutting the smaller one off at ground level to let the larger one grow freely. Is this a good idea?

Is there even a problem at all or should I just leave them be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your trees have four true leaves, transplant the seeedlings. The root systems will still be small enough that, when you empty the pot, the seedlings will separate from all or most of the soil. You will be able to gently tease the twins' roots apart from each other without killing them.

And, no, there's no problem going on in that picture at all.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go, they are about that size now and I've been meaning to move them.